# How to change wordpress theme code, text with image (Logo)?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I need to change text (LOGO) in my wordpress theme, but i don't know how?
In the header.
I tried to edit it in theme file editor.

I tried to edit it in theme file editor, when i change image with the text, image suddenly appears all good, but then when i scroll down it just corrupt.
[Text that i need to change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpYE9.png)

Code of the header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>

<?php $winta_redux_demo = get_option('redux_demo'); ?>

<head>

    <!-- Meta Tags -->

    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <?php if ( ! function_exists( 'has_site_icon' ) || ! has_site_icon() ) {?>

        <?php if(isset($winta_redux_demo['favicon']['url'])){?>

            <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo esc_url($winta_redux_demo['favicon']['url']); ?>">

        <?php } ?>

    <?php } ?>

    <?php wp_head(); ?> 


</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>

 <div id="preloader"></div>
    <!-- Progress scroll totop -->
    <div class="progress-wrap cursor-pointer">
        <svg class="progress-circle svg-content" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="-1 -1 102 102">
            <path d="M50,1 a49,49 0 0,1 0,98 a49,49 0 0,1 0,-98" />
        </svg>
    </div>
    <!-- Mouse cursor -->
    <div class="mouse-cursor cursor-outer"></div>
    <div class="mouse-cursor cursor-inner"></div>
    <!-- Navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Logo -->
            <div class="logo-wrapper valign">
                <?php if(isset($winta_redux_demo['logo_text']) && $winta_redux_demo['logo_text'] != ''){?>
                <div class="logo">
                    <h2><a href="<?php echo esc_url(home_url('/')); ?>"><?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode(esc_attr($winta_redux_demo['logo_text']));?></a><span><?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode(esc_attr($winta_redux_demo['logo_meta']));?></span></h2>
                </div>
                <?php }else{?>
                <div class="logo">
                    
                    <h2><a href="<?php echo esc_url(home_url('/')); ?>"><?php echo esc_html__( 'winta', 'winta' )?>                     </a> 
                        <span><?php echo esc_html__( 'K E T E R I N G', 'winta' )?></span></h2>
                </div>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"> <span class="icon-bar"><i class="ti-line-double"></i></span> </button>
            <!-- Navbar links -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <?php 
                wp_nav_menu( 
                    array( 
                        'theme_location' => 'primary',
                        'container' => '',
                        'menu_class' => '', 
                        'menu_id' => '',
                        'menu'            => '',
                        'container_class' => '',
                        'container_id'    => '',
                        'echo'            => true,
                        'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
                        'walker'            => new winta_wp_bootstrap_navwalker(),
                        'before'          => '',
                        'after'           => '',
                        'link_before'     => '',
                        'link_after'      => '',
                        'items_wrap'      => '<ul class=" navbar-nav ml-auto %2$s">%3$s</ul>',
                        'depth'           => 1,        
                    )
                ); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use page builders like Elementor or Visual Composer, you can change these things easily.
But usually, standard themes can be changed in the theme -> customization section, such as color, photo, etc ...
But if none of them exist, you should change this line of code:

```
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Logo -->
            <div class="logo-wrapper valign">
                <?php if(isset($winta_redux_demo['logo_text']) && $winta_redux_demo['logo_text'] != ''){?>
                <div class="logo">
                    <h2><a href="<?php echo esc_url(home_url('/')); ?>"><?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode(esc_attr($winta_redux_demo['logo_text']));?></a><span><?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode(esc_attr($winta_redux_demo['logo_meta']));?></span></h2>
                </div>
                <?php }else{?>
                <div class="logo">
                    
                    <h2><a href="<?php echo esc_url(home_url('/')); ?>"><?php echo esc_html__( 'logo', 'logo' )?>                     </a> 
                        <span><?php echo esc_html__( 'Text For YOU', 'LOGO' )?></span></h2>
                </div>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
```

Comment: Yeah I understand that is the part of code that I need to change but there is no option of importing the photo in the code. My question is how can i adapt it and import my logo (Image.png) and that code still runs smooth.

Comment: To do this, you can in between the tag
`<div class="logo">`

by using

`<img src="img_girl.jpg" alt="Girl in a jacket" width="500" height="600">`

Use the photo you want

Only in the src section should you put the URL of your image